# PyCharm Run Tool Window (Run Tab Window) is missing

Tags: python, pycharm

So recently my PyCharm is missing its run tool window that usually show the run/debug results. it is now replaced with python console and services, which is really frustrating because It's just showing gibberish and command-prompt-like format.

How do I return the run tool window back as my main run/debug window?

I have circled the tabs/windows that I meant in this pic with red circle.

Note: usually I can access this run tool window by pressing alt + 4.

Please see red circle:

[image: Please see red circle]

This is my run config:

[image: This is my run config]

This is my view tab bar, it doesn't show run (alt+4):

[image: This is my view tab bar, it doesn't show run (alt+4)]

Comment: What happens when you just run a file? Where is it running? Can you show your [Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)?

Comment: It right away goes to the python console on the bottom left corner, the one in the red circle in my picture

Comment: Please show your run configuration, it might be that you need to disable the option `Run with Python Console`

Comment: I have already disabled it. It goes to the "services" tab/window (the alt + 8 shortcut). The "run" tab is just missing.

Comment: Hey Tomerikoo, I have already added the run config SS in my question, please peruse through it if you have time, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you want the run icon pinned to your lower toolbar. (This corresponds to running whatever your last chosen configuration was.)

Two easy steps:

1º **`View -> Tool Windows -> Run`**

[image]

2º **`Right-click run icon on lower tool bar -> View Mode -> Dock Pinned`**

[image]

**Edit after OP feedback:**

If your `Run` (Alt+4) option has disappeared completely, besides trying a PyCharm reinstall it's advisable to manually clean the preference files that might be hidden. Check the following paths `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\JetBrains` and `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains`, `C:\Users\user_name\.PyCharmCE2020.x`, and `C:\Path_to_your_Project\.idea`. Some of there directories might be hidden so you'll have to check you've set them to be visible.

Even by reinstalling PyCharm some of the above configurations are likely to be kept. There's a strong possibility the **state** of whatever changes that caused `Run` to disappear is kept in files inside the above mentioned directories.

Comment: hi bad_coder thanks for your answer. But unfortunately, the run toolbar doesn't even exist. It's gone, so I can't even pinned it. do you have any more ways? I'll post the screenshot of my View list on my post

Comment: hey, you are right! I have reinstalled it twice, but the config doesn't change! but now, which preference files in those directories you want me to clean? do you know the name of the file that I need to delete?

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED!! BAD CODER I WILL UPVOTE AND CLICK THE CHECKMARK!! YOU ARE AWESOOOOMEEE!!  Anyway, for those who want to know what folder I deleted from the directory of my project, it's the ".idea" folder inside my project. just delete it, and the pycharm will create a new ".idea" folder. I also noticed that when I made new project, the new project worked just fine!! Thanks bad_coder

Answer (score 12):

1. right-click on the code.
2. `More Run/Debug`
3. click on `modify run configuration`
4. un-select `run with python console`

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally ran your code in the python console and you want to fix it, you can do the things I described below.

1 - To restore the missing 'Run' button, first click on the 'Edit Configures' option you see in the image below.

[image]

2 - Then uncheck the checkbox that says 'Run with Python Console' in the window that opens. It should look like the picture you see below

[image]

3 - Finally, save your changes by clicking the apply and ok buttons below.

[image]

And your problem will be solved. You can start Pycharm normally.