# How to correctly specify the type of a variable in Python in order to prevent unresolved reference in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

I have a function:

```py
def foo(path):
    """ 
    :param path: Path to a folder
    :type path: pathlib.Path
    """
    new_path = path / 'tmp'
    return new_path
```

which gets a `pathlib.Path` object and adds 'tmp' at the end of this path. But PyCharm shows an "unresolved reference under `path` in `new_path = path / 'tmp'`.

As it is obvious, this won't happen if the type of such variables is built-in. Note that this can be resolved if I import `from pathlib import Path` and change the `def foo(path)` to `def foo(path: Path)`. But I want to know if there is any way to do this without unnecessary imports. I read about Python typing but can't find a solution.

Comment: @CATboardBETA No worries. `Path` objects from the `pathlib` library offer such behavior implementing the division operator as a concatenation operator. So instead of the traditional `os.path.join(path, 'tmp')`, you can simply do `path / 'tmp'`

Comment: Pressing `ctrl+q` on the function I even get in the description the desired `def foo(path: Path) -> Path` (without importing `pathlib`)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes Pycharm does this. But you'll get "NameError: name 'Path' is not defined" as Path is not imported

Comment: FWIW, these imports are *not* unnecessary. It is perfectly valid for other code to inspect your functions, which requires the names to resolve properly. Unless there is a clear technical reason (e.g. cyclic imports) you *should* add the imports.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I assume that path is an object which can be passed through different modules, as it can be recognized by python as an insider and I should not use another import. So you say its not pythonic?

Comment: @masoud Any code that refers to a name should make sure that name is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below example PyCharm does issue a warning `Unresolved reference 'Path'` because in the annotation the type `Path` that type hints `argument_path` has not been imported from `pathlib`. The warning is issued both for the argument and the variable.

```py
def foo(argument_path: Path):
    """
    :param path: Path to a folder
    :type path: Path
    """
    new_path: Path = argument_path / 'tmp'
    return new_path
```

The obvious way to solve this is using `from pathlib import Path` at the top of the module.

```py
from pathlib import Path

def foo(argument_path: Path):
    new_path: Path = argument_path / 'tmp'
```

> But I want to know if there is any way to do this without unnecessary imports.

There are two ways to do this without an import, either use the fully qualified name in the annotation `pathlib.Path`

```py
def foo(argument_path: pathlib.Path):
    new_path: pathlib.Path = argument_path / 'tmp'
```

Or don't use type annotations and simply specify the type in the docstring.

PyCharm's static type checker doesn't warn you if you declare a type that can't be resolved inside the docstring. Instead, PyCharm will issue a warning when you try to use the function. In the below example no typehints were used in the signature or variable declaration, the type is only specified in the docstring.

```py
def foo3(argument_path):
    """
    :param argument_path: Path to a folder
    :type argument_path: pathlib.Path
    """
    new_path = path / 'tmp'
    return new_path

# PyCharm will issue this warning:
foo3("a_string")  # Expected type 'Path', got 'str' instead
```

Finally you are using reStructuredText syntax in the docstrings, this option should be specified in the project settings under: `Settings` `>` `Tools` `>` `Python Integrated Tools` `>` `DocString Format`

[image: image of pycharm settings integrated tools]

Comment: that solved my problem. But I tried  "use the fully qualified name in the annotation pathlib.Path" and did't work.

Comment: @masoud double check you don't have any typo, the exact example as I posted it is sure to work. Also isolate it in a single file for testing to make sure other functions in the module aren't causing an interference.

Comment: @bad_coder should mention that I have enabled the **collect run-time type information for code insight** of `Python Debugger` in settings.

Comment: I just tried [the example](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html#example) you mention and it works for me. If the problem persists try [invalidate caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html) and [Clear caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugger-python.html) -disable that option for a clear start. If it still doesn't work [wipe your temporary files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63597648). If those examples don't work there's a serious problem with the IDE that needs to be fixed first.