# Scanning files to index won't stop and PyCharm freezes

Tags: python, pycharm

I upgraded my python to version 3.9.2 and PyCharm to 2020.3.3. When I loaded my project (it is just a calculator, so rather small) I switched my interpreter. Then it started scanning files to index and freezed. The bar was on the same place for an hour. Also, if I pause the scanning and I run the main.py file, it gives me import errors. I tried all the things they said here [Pycharm 5.0.1: Scanning files to index taking forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976058/pycharm-5-0-1-scanning-files-to-index-taking-forever), but it won't work for me.

Comment: You can utilize the "Invalidate cache and restart" option available in the file menu.

Comment: Stil the same. :(

Comment: See the bottom section of this post [for clearing temporary files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63597648) Also, strong possibility that some venv's haven't been cleared by the IDE automatically if you want to check [here are the instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66057514).

Comment: The .iml file is already right. What must I do with the first link?

Comment: @Jareg the 1st link in the previous comment, at the bottom there's a paragraph called `Edit after OP feedback:` which has 3 file paths to temporary IDE info (those may have to be deleted and recreated). But I'm starting to think this question needs some extra details, what exactly is your IDE indexing? If it's a large project it makes sense that it takes time to index, if it's a small project the indexing should be reasonably fast. You don't really specify...Please edit the question to include more details.

Comment: @bad_coder Is there any more details you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229277/discussion-between-jareg-and-bad-coder).

Comment: @bad_coder I excluded my whole project except for python 3.9 which you can't. And it is still not working

Comment: @Jareg check the [log files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) and edit the question to include all steps that you have taken.